# Swift - Compile error when constraining associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

So I don't have to write much code to replicate my error - it might be that I should be using generics in this case, but it feels like my solution should work. So the following block of code gives me a "Type DCServiceClient does not conform to protocol DMServiceClient":

```
protocol DMServiceEndpoint { }
protocol DCServiceEndpoint: DMServiceEndpoint { }

protocol DMServiceClient {
    typealias Endpoint: DMServiceEndpoint
}

class DCServiceClient: DMServiceClient {
    typealias Endpoint = DCServiceEndpoint
}
```

However, if I remove the constraint on the associated type (Endpoint), it compiles without any issues. Because DCServiceEndpoint conforms to the constraint (DMServiceEndpoint) it seems like it should compile. Any ideas as to what I'm missing here? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol DMServiceEndpoint { }
protocol DCServiceEndpoint: DMServiceEndpoint { }

protocol DMServiceClient {
    typealias Endpoint: DMServiceEndpoint
}
class DCServiceClient: DMServiceClient {
    typealias Endpoint = newClass // implementation a class conforms to  EndPoint
}
// add new class conforms to DMServiceEndpoint
class newClass: DCServiceEndpoint {}
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't know what the concrete class is at this point. I only know that it will conform to a protocol. Our service client class is pretty generic. After playing around with it for a while I'm starting to think what we want is not possible.